# Google Bigquery Standard SQL - Count of id that have searched for destination and not booked

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table of search data in an airline app.
I want to write a query that outputs the number of visitors that have searched for only one airport in New York and not any other in New York. So essentially work out the number of people that search for the one airport and don't try any other airports in New York.

Assume that New York airports are JFK, LGA, EWR and MSY.

Table would look something along the lines of:

```
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
| visitor_id | searched_to | searched_from | booked|
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|     11     |     JFK     |      LCY      |   N   |
|     11     |     LGA     |      LCY      |   N   |
|     11     |     EWR     |      LCY      |   N   |
|     12     |     JFK     |      LCY      |   N   |
|     13     |     MSY     |      LTN      |   Y   |
|     14     |     JFK     |      LTN      |   N   |
|     14     |     JFK     |      LGW      |   N   |
|     14     |     EWR     |      LCY      |   Y   |
|     15     |     GOA     |      MSY      |   N   |
```

e.g. Visitor 12 and 15 would be someone that I would want to include in a count for those didn't extend their search.
e.g. Visitor 14 would be someone that I would want to include in a count for those that did extend their search.

Essentially I would want a count of:

- did not extend search and not book
- did extend search and did not book
- did extend search and did book

Hope that all makes sense? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, provide expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

first step is to find which visitor did what

```
#standardSQL
SELECT visitor_id, 'Y' = MAX(booked) booked,
  1 < COUNTIF(searched_to IN ('JFK', 'LGA', 'EWR', 'MSY') 
      OR searched_from IN ('JFK', 'LGA', 'EWR', 'MSY')) extended
FROM `project.dataset.your_table`
GROUP BY visitor_id
```

if you will try it with dummy data as below

```
WITH `project.dataset.your_table` AS (
  SELECT 11 visitor_id, 'JFK' searched_to, 'LCY' searched_from, 'N' booked UNION ALL
  SELECT 11, 'LGA', 'LCY', 'N' UNION ALL
  SELECT 11, 'EWR', 'LCY', 'N' UNION ALL
  SELECT 12, 'JFK', 'LCY', 'N' UNION ALL
  SELECT 13, 'MSY', 'LTN', 'Y' UNION ALL
  SELECT 14, 'JFK', 'LTN', 'N' UNION ALL
  SELECT 14, 'JFK', 'LGW', 'N' UNION ALL
  SELECT 14, 'EWR', 'LCY', 'Y' UNION ALL
  SELECT 15, 'GOA', 'MSY', 'N' 
)
```

result will be as

```
Row visitor_id  booked  extended     
1   11          false   true     
2   12          false   false    
3   15          false   false    
4   13          true    false    
5   14          true    true
```

next step is do final count

```
#standardSQL
SELECT extended, booked, COUNT(1) cnt
FROM (
  SELECT visitor_id, 'Y' = MAX(booked) booked,
    1 < COUNTIF(searched_to IN ('JFK', 'LGA', 'EWR', 'MSY') 
        OR searched_from IN ('JFK', 'LGA', 'EWR', 'MSY')) extended
  FROM `project.dataset.your_table`
  GROUP BY visitor_id
)
GROUP BY extended, booked
```

this will return

```
Row extended    booked  cnt  
1   false       false   2    
2   false       true    1    
3   true        true    1    
4   true        false   1
```

You can test, play with whole query using dummy data from your question

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.your_table` AS (
  SELECT 11 visitor_id, 'JFK' searched_to, 'LCY' searched_from, 'N' booked UNION ALL
  SELECT 11, 'LGA', 'LCY', 'N' UNION ALL
  SELECT 11, 'EWR', 'LCY', 'N' UNION ALL
  SELECT 12, 'JFK', 'LCY', 'N' UNION ALL
  SELECT 13, 'MSY', 'LTN', 'Y' UNION ALL
  SELECT 14, 'JFK', 'LTN', 'N' UNION ALL
  SELECT 14, 'JFK', 'LGW', 'N' UNION ALL
  SELECT 14, 'EWR', 'LCY', 'Y' UNION ALL
  SELECT 15, 'GOA', 'MSY', 'N' 
)
SELECT extended, booked, COUNT(1) cnt
FROM (
  SELECT visitor_id, 'Y' = MAX(booked) booked,
    1 < COUNTIF(searched_to IN ('JFK', 'LGA', 'EWR', 'MSY') 
        OR searched_from IN ('JFK', 'LGA', 'EWR', 'MSY')) extended
  FROM `project.dataset.your_table`
  GROUP BY visitor_id
)
GROUP BY extended, booked
```

Note: in question's title you mentioned `searched for destination` but in question itself you mentioned visitor #15 to be included - so I used both searched_to and searched_from in filtering. you can remove filter for search_from if needed

Answer (score 0):

Try this for 1st query.
Please check if this query is providing the required output.

```
SELECT visitor_id, count(*)
FROM tableName t
WHERE search_to IN ('JFK', 'LGA', 'EWR', 'MSY')
AND NOT IN (SELECT visitor_id FROM tableName temp WHERE t.visitor_id = temp.visitor_id AND booked = 'Y' and search_to IN ('JFK', 'LGA', 'EWR', 'MSY'))
GROUP BY visitor_id
HAVING count(*) = 1;
```

With a few modification, 2nd and 3rd query will be ready to use. Try out yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your response Rahul, just wasn't quite what I was looking for